# How to Iterate Map value in Struts2 Dojo autocompleter

Tags: dictionary, struts2, autocomplete, dojo

I'm using Struts2 dojo autocompleter and I need to Iterate Map values instead of list and need to send corresponding map key to back end. How can I do that.

```
< sx:autocompleter label="Select a road" list="roadsMap" name="roadsInColombo" resultsLimit="-1">
```

Here I can display the values of roadsMap (this is Hash `map<String, String>`) by using list.
But How can I send corresponding map key after select the value to back end.

Comment: if this is a new application, please do not use Dojo tags as they are no longer supported by struts2

Comment: Then what are the best options we can use for autocompleter with localization.

Comment: use struts2-Jquery-plugin which is under active development and have a lots of features

Comment: Ok. I'll try Umesh to change. Thanks for your advise and I have done this thing using keyName attribute. It means we need to use < sx:autocompleter label="Select a road" list="roadsMap" listKey="key" listValue="value" keyName="roadsInColombo" resultsLimit="-1">. Thanks again for your help and advise.

Comment: I do not have any exp working with DOJO tags and i advised it ,since tags has been deprecated so any bug or any such issues will not be addressed at all in any future S2 release.